# Create new class based on existing for use in JavaFX

Tags: inheritance, intellij-idea, javafx

I want to make a class DogView  that can be accessed in jafaFX.

I don't want to change the existing class Dog

```
public class Dog {
    String breed;
    int age;
    String color;

    void barking() { }

    void hungry() { }

    void sleeping() { }
}
```

So what do I have to do ?

```
public class DogView extends Dos {

    .... Is there a trick in Intellij Idea?
}
```

Comment: You might start with a `TableView<Dog>`, like this [`TableView<Person>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm), then edit your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits any specific problem you encounter.

Comment: I don't know what the `Dos` class is, but assuming this is a typo and supposed to be `Dog`: You can only extend a single class in java. Furthermore only classes that extend `Node` (possibly indirectly) can be put in a scene. This means you cannot create a class extending `Dog` that can be added to a scene. Create a class extending some kind of `Node` and add a `ObjectProperty<Dog>` that displays the properties of the `Dog` associated with the view...

Comment: If the previous comments don't lead you in the right direction, you should try to be more precise about what you mean. Your `Dog` class can already be "accessed" in JavaFX. What do you really mean there?

Comment: I need Stringproperty breed to show it in a tableView.

Comment: You don't *need* that - you can use a `TableView` perfectly well with a POJO - though it makes some things simpler. The real question is: how do you want to display the data?